Why is ICollection<T> treated differently in collection expression syntax?
I was checking (just being curious) how collection expression syntax, introduced in C# 12, gets translated into IL code, and specifically what exact data types are used under the hood.
Most cases were pretty straightforward:
Collection<int> a = [5, 2];
IEnumerable<int> b = [5, 2];
IReadOnlyList<int> c = [5, 2];

gets translated to:
Collection<int> a = new Collection<int> { 5, 2 };
IEnumerable<int> b = new <>z__ReadOnlyArray<int>(new int[2] { 5, 2 });
IReadOnlyList<int> c = new <>z__ReadOnlyArray<int>(new int[2] { 5, 2 });

Nothing surprising here. The next one, however, puzzles me.
ICollection<int> d = [5, 2];

gets translated, in debug mode, to:
List<int> list = new List<int>();
CollectionsMarshal.SetCount(list, 2);
Span<int> span = CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list);
int num = 0;
span[num] = 5;
num++;
span[num] = 2;
num++;
ICollection<int> d = list;

In release mode, the only thing that changes is the removal of d variable—the list variable is used directly where d was used in the original code.
A rough and absolutely non-scientific benchmark of the two approaches shows the following results, when constructing the collection 100,000,000 times:



Number of items in the array
Duration with IEnumerable
Duration with ICollection




2
1.0 s.
1.5 s.


25
7.4 s.
4.1 s.


32
7.4 s.
5.0 s.



It seems that both approaches are comparable in terms of performance: the first one is better when there is a small number of elements, whereas the second one outperforms it when the number of elements start to be higher.
However, the compiler seems to pick an approach based on a type, rather than on a number of actual values in the collection.
What could be the reasons to have this second approach at all, given that the compiler-generated type <>z__ReadOnlyArray`1'<!T> does implement ICollection<T> anyway?

Are you saying that the compiler should create an instance of <>z__ReadOnlyArray<int> for ICollection<int>? But ICollection<int> is supposed to be mutable.

@Sweeper: I see. That's smart. Indeed, in the very first case with Collection<T>, there was nothing created. As for IEnumerable<T> and IReadOnlyList<T>, they are both already read-only. Makes sense. Can you promote your comment to an answer in order for me to accept it?

ICollection<T> is mutable and has methods like Add, so it makes more sense for the compiler to also create an instance of a mutable collection type, as opposed to a read-only array and have it throw NotSupportedException when you try to Add.
Compare this to when the type is IReadOnlyCollection<T>, the compiler does use a read-only array in this case.
IReadOnlyCollection<int> x = [1,2,3];
// compiles to
IReadOnlyCollection<int> readOnlyCollection = new <>z__ReadOnlyArray<int>(array);

See also my answer to this question.

well ICollection<T> does have a bool IsReadOnly { get; } so it's not strictly always mutable..

@IvanPetrov Yeah, perhaps "has mutating methods like Add" is a better wording?

it is not-read-only (see my answer)...

While ICollection<T> isn't strictly a mutable interface because it has bool IsReadOnly { get; }, a distinction seems to have been made by the CSharp design team for two categories of interfaces wrt to the collection expression feature:

'read-only' interfaces (IEnumerable<T>/IReadOnlyCollection<T>/IReadOnlyList<T>)
'mutable' interfaces (ICollection<T>/IList<T>):


Effectively, this intentionally bifurcates the interfaces into two
important categories. The 'read only' interfaces, which support no
mutation, and the 'mutable interfaces' which do. Our feeling is that
for the latter, there is no real better choice than List. It is the
'bread and butter' type the BCL has for this purpose that the entire
ecosystem understands and feels comfortable with. For the domain of
mutable-sequences, it is extremely good and does its job well.

This was later confirmed as design choice in Collection expressions - compiler synthesized types
